# Calculating YTD change for weekly data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with weekly data like below:

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 2 |
| 1/7/2022 | 3 | 5 | 9 | 4 |
| 1/14/2022 | 4 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| 1/21/2022 | 4 | 6 | 1 | 4 |

I want to create an YTD change table like the below where YTD change is calculated as ('last value of the year' - 'first value of the year') / 'first value of the year' (i.e., basic % change).
I have just started out so am not sure how to approach this in the most efficient manner.

Desired output format:

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | x | x | x | x |
| 2021 | x | x | x | x |
| 2020 | x | x | x | x |
| 2019 | x | x | x | x |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) (the [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) method is closely related by can only be applied on consecutive rows in a group).

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values('Date').set_index('Date')
df.groupby(df.index.year).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1].subtract(x.iloc[0]).div(x.iloc[0]))
```

Result on the sample data:

```
         A    B     C   D
Date                
2022   0.0  0.2  -0.8  1.0
```